# JSONWriter Cannot Access member of class in Joda library

Tags: java, struts2

I've encountered a very annoying bug that appears to be environment related as none of my coworkers experience the same bug. I've be assigned an old struts project that builds into a war and is deployed on tomcat. I reiterate that none of my coworkers experience this same error so it is most likely environment or configuration related. I have tried to mimic their environments as much as possible to no avail. Ask for any info you need, I'll provide what I can.

The error occurs after a search is made. I debug and follow the thread, it goes through the code fine, returns ActionSupport.SUCCESS and I guess somewhere within struts the issue occurs.

```
ERROR(CommonsLogger.java:38) - Exception processing the result.
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.array(JSONWriter.java:481)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:102)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.createJSONString(JSONResult.java:202)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:176)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.executeResult(RestActionInvocation.java:240)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.processResult(RestActionInvocation.java:197)
    at org.apache.struts2.rest.RestActionInvocation.invoke(RestActionInvocation.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.execute(DefaultActionProxy.java:147)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.company.servletstore.NdcFilter.doFilter(NdcFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.processCustom(JSONWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:168)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:134)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:390)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:231)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:226)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Do you understand the exception?

Comment: It seems like the JSONWriter is trying to access a private inner class. The fact that I get it and others dont confuses me though

Comment: Do others use json result in their environments that works with joda datetime fields?

Comment: The others use identical code and perform the same action. The application is a website. My coworkers create the war the same way I do, deploy the same way, perform the same actions, and their search results are shown on the view. My search results in the above error

Comment: Could you exclude from the result some filed that contains dependency on joda library?

Comment: I've attempted and there does not seem to be a change. That being said, its old code I've only recently started working with and may have missed something. I'm continuing to try and remove all instances of the library. However, while that may lead to additional diagnosis, it does not explain why I get an error and others do not. I'll keep trying though to see if I can gather more information.

Comment: Unable to remove the library from the relevant part of the application. Its too widespread and would result in removing and changing too much code to be a realistic diagnosis